Laravel is sending GET instead of POST request while I am actually using post method
PHP version: 7.4.33
Laravel version: 5.8
when I hit the post route, it shows in the error page that I sent it as Get, and this route supports Post.

this is the error msg: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

The route I hit is install/db/configuration

The details in error msg shows me the method is Get.
enter image description here

However, the Method is Post either in the Route or View File.

I dd($request) for the method in db method controller and it shows prints Post

I tried all the cache clear commands and the optimize.

I even made sure the route in the AppServiceProvider hits http not https.

Here is the Route File:


<?php


Route::post('install/db/configuration'  ,'InstallController@db')->name('store.db.configurations');

Route::get('install/app'                , 'InstallController@installation')->name('installation');
Route::get('install/configuration'      , 'InstallController@configurations')->name('show.configurations');
Route::post('install/configuration'     , 'InstallController@store')->name('store.configurations');
Route::post('install/app/configuration' , 'InstallController@app')->name('store.app.configurations');
Route::get('install/complete'           , 'InstallController@complete')->name('complete.installation');


Here is the Controller:

class InstallController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(RedirectIfInstalled::class);
    }

    public function installation(Requirement $requirement)
    {
        return view('install.new', compact('requirement'));
    }

    public function configurations(Requirement $requirement)
    {
        if (! $requirement->satisfied()) {
            return redirect()->name('installation');
        }

        return view('install.db_configuration', compact('requirement'));
    }

    public function db(InstallDatabaseRequest $request,Database $database,App $app)
    {
        $database->setup($request->db);
        $app->setup($request);

        return view('install.app_configuration');
    }

    public function app(InstallAppRequest $request,FinalInstallation $final,AdminAccount $admin)
    {
        $final->setup($request);
        $admin->setup($request);

        return redirect()->route('complete.installation');
    }

    public function complete()
    {
        if (env('APP_INSTALLED') == true) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.home');
        }

        DotenvEditor::setKey('APP_INSTALLED', 'true')->save();

        return view('install.complete');
    }
}

Here the setup method in both database and app classes:
class Database
{
    public function setup($data)
    {
        $this->checkDatabaseConnection($data);
        $this->setEnvVariables($data);
    }

    private function checkDatabaseConnection($data)
    {
        $this->setupDatabaseConnectionConfig($data);

        DB::connection('mysql')->reconnect();
        DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
    }
    // code goes here
}

class App
{
    public function setup($request)
    {
        $this->generateAppKey();
        $this->setEnvVariables($request);
        $this->setAppSettings($request);
    }

    private function generateAppKey()
    {
        Artisan::call('key:generate', ['--force' => true]);
    }

    private function setEnvVariables($request)
    {
        $env = DotenvEditor::load();

        $env->setKey('APP_ENV'    , 'local');
        $env->setKey('APP_DEBUG'  , 'true');
        $env->setKey('APP_URL'    , url('/') );

        $env->save();
    }
   // code goes here
}



Here is the Some of the View:

<form method="POST" action="{{ url(route('store.db.configurations')) }}" class="form-horizontal">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="box">
         // lots of code goes here for the styling
        <div class="content-buttons clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right install-button">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>


AppServiceProcider Code:

public function boot()
    {
        if (app()->environment('production')) {
           app('url')->forceScheme('http');
        }
    }


Here is route:list for the install/db/configuration route:

|        | GET|HEAD                               | install/app                             | installation
  | App\Http\Controllers\InstallController@installation                       | web,App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfInstalled   
                                                                         |
|        | POST                                   | install/app/configuration               | store.app.configurations        
  | App\Http\Controllers\InstallController@app                                | web,App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfInstalled   
                                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | install/complete                        | complete.installation
  | App\Http\Controllers\InstallController@complete                           | web,App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfInstalled   
                                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | install/configuration                   | show.configurations
  | App\Http\Controllers\InstallController@configurations                     | web,App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfInstalled   
                                                                         |
|        | POST                                   | install/configuration                   | store.configurations
  | App\Http\Controllers\InstallController@store                              | web,App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfInstalled   
                                                                         |
|        | POST                                   | install/db/configuration                | store.db.configurations
  | App\Http\Controllers\InstallController@db                                 | web,App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfInstalled   


Network tab




Bring up your browser's developer tools and watch the Network tab as you make the request. You're most likely being redirected (usually happens with HTTP -> HTTPS), which turns a POST into a GET

I think you've made it very clear about the route/method being defined as POST. But, can you explain more about the steps you took to hit the route, what's the value of $request inside db method, what $database->setup($request->db);  $app->setup($request); does, etc.?

Check your APP_URL in your .env. If you have that set to a https:// link, and you're forcing http in production with app('url')->forceScheme('http'); (which, really, you should be enforcing https in production), then you're going to get the redirect I was talking about, which breaks your POST route

@aynber
the request is http, here is the data from network tab:
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/install/db/configuration ,
Request Method: GET

@aynber
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000 , so it is indeed http

$request->db: array:5 [▼
"host" => "127.0.0.1"
"port" => "3306"
"username" => "root"
"password" => ""
"database" => "o2mor"
] , and for the rest, I updated the code in the question
@Rexy

Did you watch the network tab of your developer console to see if it's doing a POST request initially, or if it's doing some sort of redirect?

configuration 405 document and  stylesheets?v=1723480592 302-stylesheet / Redirect and  javascript?v=1723480592 302 script / Redirec

the above comment is what is shown in the network tab, first the configuration route comes as 405 then redirection of stylesheet and javascript.. does that help? @aynber

It's really hard to tell what that information is. Look for just the request to install/db/configuration, and see if there are one or more hits to that. A screenshot of the Network tab with that request would be helpful.

@aynber I added screenshots

Odd, there isn't a redirect. I'm stymied. All I can suggest at this point is look at the source code in the browser and make sure the form looks correct, and that there's no other forms or a href links pointing to the configuration link.
